# What is the order of the config file for NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have the following config files and locations:

```
etc/ngnix/nginix.conf
var/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject
etc/ngnix/conf.d/default.conf
etc/ngnix/conf.d/web.conf
```

I'm confused regarding each conf file role, rules, when to use one or another, are they loaded one after another, or just one, are directives overwriting ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `nginx` configuration file is called `nginx.conf` and on most systems is located at `etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

`nginx.conf` may optionally contain `include` statements to read parts of the configuration from other files. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for more. Read your `nginx.conf` file to identify which files and directories are sourced and in which context and which order.

Some distributions are delivered with an `nginx.conf` file that sources additional files from directories such as `/conf.d/` and `/sites-enabled/`.

There is also a convention on some distributions to symlink files between `/sites-available/` and `/sites-enabled/`.

The `nginx -T` command (uppercase `T`) is useful to list the entire configuration across all the included files.

Comment: OP has two files in /etc/ngnix/conf.d. In what order are they processed? Alphabetical/lexical order? Filesystem/directory order?

Comment: Found it! If you use an include with a wildcard, such as  "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;", the resulting files are sorted alphabetically, per https://serverfault.com/a/361163/200763.